# MemoryMappedFile low-integrity .Net 5

Tags: c#, ipc, .net-5

I'm using a `MemoryMappedFile` in .NET 5 and encounter a problem that seemed to have been solved long ago.

I use it for inter-process communication so it must be located in ring 0. For that to achieve I use the name prefix `Global`:

```
var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(@"Global\test", 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

This works fine for privileged processes.

For non-privileged ones I want to use

```
mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(@"Global\test", MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite);
```

But that fails with an "UnauthorizedAccessException".

The solution that worked for .NET Framework up to 4.8 was to explicitly set `MemoryMappedFileSecurity` as described e.g. here: [Gaining access to a MemoryMappedFile from low-integrity process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887587/gaining-access-to-a-memorymappedfile-from-low-integrity-process)

Unfortunately the `MemoryMappedFileSecurity` does no longer seem to exist and `MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting` (or `CreateNew`) do no have an overload for that or similar either.

### Interim solution

.Net5  mostlikely won't get that missing feature. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/941

As a workaround I use the P/Invoke approach. In case someone has the same problem here is a working solution using null DACL to grant all access

```
private void CreateFile()
{
    try
    {
        using(var secAttribs = CreateSecAttribs())
        {
            memBuffer = NativeMethods.CreateFileMapping(
                            UIntPtr.MaxValue,
                            secAttribs,
                            (uint)FileMapProtection.PAGE_READWRITE,
                            0,
                            (uint)MemOffset.TotalSize,
                            BufferName);

            if (memBuffer == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                uint lasterror = NativeMethods.GetLastError();
                throw new Win32Exception((int)lasterror, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error creating shared memory. Errorcode is {0}", lasterror));
            }
            
            IntPtr accessor = NativeMethods.MapViewOfFile(memBuffer, (uint)ViewAccess.FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, (int)MemOffset.TotalSize);

            if (accessor == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                uint lasterror = NativeMethods.GetLastError();
                throw new Win32Exception((int)lasterror, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error creating shared memory view. Errorcode is {0}", lasterror));
            }
            
            //Do sth with accessor using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        memBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        throw;
    }
}

private static NativeMethods.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES CreateSecAttribs()
{
    //Create the descriptor with a null DACL --> Everything is granted.
    RawSecurityDescriptor sec = new RawSecurityDescriptor(ControlFlags.DiscretionaryAclPresent, null, null, null, null);


    return new NativeMethods.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(sec);
}
```

For reference:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    #region Structures

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES : IDisposable
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;

        public SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
        {
            nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
            lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            bInheritHandle = 1;
        }

        public SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(RawSecurityDescriptor sec) :
            this()
        {
            byte[] binDACL = new byte[sec.BinaryLength];
            sec.GetBinaryForm(binDACL, 0);

            lpSecurityDescriptor = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sec.BinaryLength);

            Marshal.Copy(binDACL, 0, lpSecurityDescriptor, sec.BinaryLength);
        }

        ~SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {

            }

            if (lpSecurityDescriptor != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpSecurityDescriptor);
                lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region General imports

    [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "CloseHandle", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetLastError", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern uint GetLastError();

    #endregion

    #region Memory Mapped Files imports

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileMapping", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern IntPtr CreateFileMapping(UIntPtr hFile, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpAttributes, uint flProtect, uint dwMaximumSizeHigh, uint dwMaximumSizeLow, string lpName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "MapViewOfFile", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern IntPtr MapViewOfFile(IntPtr hFileMappingObject, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwFileOffsetHigh, uint dwFileOffsetLow, uint /* UIntPtr */ dwNumberOfBytesToMap);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "UnmapViewOfFile", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VariantBool)]
    internal static extern bool UnmapViewOfFile(IntPtr lpBaseAddress);

    #endregion
}
```

### Update

Still no official integration until .Net 7
Adam Sitnik was so friendly to manually recreate MemoryMappedFileSecurity and Wrappers for .Net7.
See https://gist.github.com/adamsitnik/6370b05b9e80bc14b62ac6efe5d1e2e2#file-mmfs-cs-L41-L184
You might need to add CreateOrOpen() based on .Net4 or remove the ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST error case in CreateCore()

### Managed Solution

This works when first called by a windows service and then by a user program (and of course vv).

```
var everyoneRule = new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(
    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
    MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite,
    AccessControlType.Allow);

MemoryMappedFileSecurity mmfSec = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
mmfSec.AddAccessRule(everyoneRule);

mmf = MemoryMappedFileFactory.Create(@"Global\Test", 1024, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, mmfSec, HandleInheritability.None);
```

Comment: .NET 4 is .NET *Core* 5. Answers that targeted .NET Old may not work in a cross-platform runtime like .NET Core - a Windows solution won't work on Linux or vice versa. You may be able to fix this by targeting a specific runtime, eg instead of targeting `net5.0` in your csproj file use `net5.0-windows`

Comment: Needs more [customer requests](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/941), be sure to speak up.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Nope. App is already set to net5.0-windows

Comment: @HansPassant kind of difficult when MS have locked the thread :(

Comment: hi @TomB can you write exactly how to use your interim solution? I get the same issue as yours but I don't know how to use your code in  MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(..).
Many thanks.

Comment: @QuocNguyen System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile does not support this. You must use the P/Invoke approach. CreateOrOpen needs to be implemented yourself. CreateFileMapping From MSDN: If the object exists before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object (with its current size, not the specified size), and GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.