# How do I craft a SystemAcl object from access control list represented as a string?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, acl, sid

Code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424623/57428) P/Invokes `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW()` WinAPI function to convert the following "magic string"

```
S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)
```

into a security descriptor object which is then used to set access control on a named pipe. The "magic string" is actually a so-called *system access control list*, also mentioned as *SACL* or *system ACL* in MSDN.

I'm trying to make use of .NET class `System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity` to achieve the same effect without P/Invoke. Looks like I need to create a `SecurityIdentifier` object but when I pass the string representation of ACL shown above into `SecurityIdentifier` constructor I get `ArgumentException` so it looks like it's not a proper SDDL string.

I tried to use `RawSecurityDescriptor` which I could later convert into SDDL form and pass the conversion result into `SecurityIdentifier` constructor. If I construct `RawSecurityDescriptor` from the string above I get a descriptor with empty SACL (SystemAcl getter returns `S:`). However `RawSecurityDescriptor` has a setter for `SystemAcl` too so maybe I could craft that myself and assign it to `SystemAcl` field.

I've looked into quite a lot of examples and I still cannot figure out how I would convert the string shown above into a `SystemAcl`. Is there any description of how those all-caps parts should be interpreted and converted into `SystemAcl`?

Comment: Are you interested in general case, or specifically in this one string?

Comment: @Evk Either of those would help. I found this explanation of "ACE strings"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/ace-strings and I understand when the string means but I cannot figure out how to get it translated into anything usable.

Comment: in what question/problem ? you want set (or better just create) object with Low Mandatory  Label or what is target ?

Comment: @RbMm `NamedPipeServerStream` accepts `PipeSecurity` object. Would be nice to have the pipe server started in a regular process such that it accepts requests from "low integrity" processes.

Comment: @sharptooth - i dont know *.net*, and how do this in such environment, but this very easy can be done in win32/native api

Comment: @RbMm I linked to an answer which contains code which P/Invokes WinAPI functions to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @sharptooth - not need call `SetSecurityInfo` or `SetKernelObjectSecurity` - need from begin create pipe with security descriptor. `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` correct used for convert string form to binary. and than need use this inside `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`